# How to copy a range of lines from a start and end pattern (excluding start & end pattern) and paste into a third pattern of the same file

Tags: awk, sed

Original file

```
.
.
. 
startpattern
   text to copy 1
   test to copy 2
endpattern
.
.
.
thirdpattern
```

Result file

```
.
.
. 
startpattern
   text to copy 1
   test to copy 2
endpattern
.
.
.
thirdpattern
   text to copy 1
   test to copy 2
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty straight-forward with the scriptable editor `ed`. The core command is:

```
/startpattern/+1, /endpattern/-1 t /thirdpattern/
```

You could change the file with the command-line:

```
printf '%s\n' '/startpattern/+1, /endpattern/-1 t /thirdpattern/' w q | ed -s filename
```

... which pipes three commands into `ed`'s input buffer: the main command, the `w`rite command, and the `q`uit command.

You would/should tighten the regular expressions on each of the patterns to be sure that you're capturing the correct lines. The +1 and -1 on the first two patterns adjust the match forwards and backwards to exclude the lines with those two patterns.